# Looping through XML in .NET?

Tags: c#, xml

I have some XML that looks something like the one below

```
<DriveLayout>
<Drive totalSpace="16" VolumeGroup="dg01" />
<Drive totalSpace="32" VolumeGroup="dg01" />
<Drive totalSpace="64" VolumeGroup="dg02" />
<Drive totalSpace="64" VolumeGroup="dg02" />
<VolumeGroups>
<VolumeGroup VolumeGroup="dg01" storageTier="1" />
<VolumeGroup VolumeGroup="dg02" storageTier="2" />
</VolumeGroups>
</DriveLayout>
```

I need a way to go back through the XML and add the attribute storageTier to each individual Drive node.  Is there a way to loop through each drive node and grab the VolumeGroup then get the cooresponding storageTier out of the XML in the VolumeGroup node?  I then need to inject the correct storageTier back into the XML drive node.  I'm using the System.XML that's in C#.

Thanks

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the newer XML Classes in 3.5 ( i.e. XDocument,XElement,XAttribute)

Comment: I'm doing a feature request for a site and it runs off 2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need XPath ( [check this out](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318499) )

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
var xml =
    @"<DriveLayout>
<Drive totalSpace='16' VolumeGroup='dg01' />
<Drive totalSpace='32' VolumeGroup='dg01' />
<Drive totalSpace='64' VolumeGroup='dg02' />
<Drive totalSpace='64' VolumeGroup='dg02' />
<VolumeGroups>
<VolumeGroup VolumeGroup='dg01' storageTier='1' />
<VolumeGroup VolumeGroup='dg02' storageTier='2' />
</VolumeGroups>
</DriveLayout>
";

doc.LoadXml(xml);
var volumeGroups = doc.SelectNodes("/DriveLayout/VolumeGroups/VolumeGroup");
var storageTiers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
if (volumeGroups != null)
{
    foreach (var volumeGroup in volumeGroups)
    {
        var volumeGroupElement = (XmlElement) volumeGroup;
        storageTiers.Add(
            volumeGroupElement.Attributes["VolumeGroup"].Value,
            volumeGroupElement.Attributes["storageTier"].Value);
    }
}

var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/DriveLayout/Drive");
if (nodes == null)
{
    return;
}

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    var element = (XmlElement) node;
    var volumeGroupAttribute = element.Attributes["VolumeGroup"];
    if (volumeGroupAttribute == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    var volumeGroup = volumeGroupAttribute.Value;

    var newStorageTier = doc.CreateAttribute("storageTier");
    newStorageTier.Value = storageTiers[volumeGroup];
    element.Attributes.Append(newStorageTier);
}
```

Comment: "You gonna finish that example?"

Comment: Useful to see the completed example. Saying that, this algorithm is O(n^2), which is totally unnecessary. Plus, I think it just shows how nice LINQ is for these sorts of scenarios.

Comment: @Noldorin: you're right; I didn't stop and make a dictionary. I'll fix that so we're comparing apples to better apples.

Comment: @John: Ok, sounds good. I'm still hoping the OP will see the beauty of LINQ though. :)

Comment: The code I am working on uses .NET 2.0 to run instead of 3.5 thus var is not supported anyway you could help me with the data types?

Answer (score 7):

This task can be done very succinctly using LINQ to XML. What is more, it uses simple LINQ queries and a dictionary to give an algorithm that runs in linear time.

```
var storageTiers = doc.Root.Element("VolumeGroups").Elements().ToDictionary(
    el => (string)el.Attribute("VolumeGroup"),
    el => (string)el.Attribute("storageTier"));
foreach (var driveElement in doc.Root.Elements("Drive"))
{
    driveElement.SetAttributeValue("storageTier", 
        storageTiers[(string)driveEl.Attribute("VolumeGroup")]);
}
```

If you are using C# 3.0, then this is without doubt the best way to go (unless your XML file is enormous and you need high efficiency, which seems unlikely).

Comment: I get errors on the doc.Root it says that Root is undefined.  Is there another library I need to add or ...?

Comment: @Splashlin: Yeah, the reference to the library is not included by default even in .NET 3.5 projects, so you'll need to reference `System.Xml.Linq`. Also, to load the docment, you just want to use `XDocument.Load(...`).

Comment: @Noldorin I added the System.Xml.Linq and it didn't help with my error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Splashline: Sorry... you need to import the namespace too! Add `using System.Xml.Linq;` to the top of the file.

Comment: @Noldorin, yeah I have that in my file and it still isn't recognizing it.

Comment: @Noldorin it appears to be tring to find it in System.Xml.XmlDocument even though I have Linq in the namespace now

Comment: @Splashlin: Notice that you want `XDocument`, not `XmlDocument` (as with `XElement` rather than `XmlElement`, etc.).

Comment: @Noldorin, thanks I just figured out that System.Xml and System.Xml.Linq don't play nice together.  I moved all the stuff to XDocument and but it doesn't recognize your ToDictionary command and this line  xsl.Transform(doc, null, sw); no longer works.

Comment: @Splashlin: I'm not sure what you'll need to do about the XSLT transform stuff. Regarding ToDictionary, you also need to import the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: Regarding your second error, XSLT transformation can be done quite simply in LINQ to XML too. See this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675186.aspx

Comment: @Noldorin I have the XSLT working and got the ToDictonary working.  the errors I get now are on the line 
   el => (string)el.Attribute("VolumeGroup"),el => (string)el.Attribute("storageTier"));

It gives me errors on
1) invalid expression '>'
2) invalid expression term 'string'
3) ) expected
4) invalid term ','
5) ; expected

Some of those are repeated more than once later.

Thanks again for all of your help.  I can't tell you how much I am learning here (even if it seems like I'm only asking questions)

Comment: @Splashlin: Ah, so it seems you have .NET 3.5 installed (and thus can reference the LINQ assemblies), but are only using C# 2.0. Sorry - I had assumed you noticed this from the question. If there is any possibility of converting the project to C# 3.0/.NET 3.5, that would be the easiest solution. Anyway, I'm glad to hear you're learning things from this - hopefully that will include LINQ when you get it working. :)

Comment: @Noldorin I gave u ups on every single one of your comments for your help in trying to get it to work.  Moving to C# 3.0 wasn't possible so I implemented the other solution even though I had to modify it and I know it's not as efficient.

Comment: @Splashlin: Fair enough, and no worries. Hopefully this answer with help if you decide to move to .NET 3.5 though, or for someone else perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

What was wrong with XSLT ([Question on XPATH for an XSLT File And XSLT If Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155635/question-on-xpath-for-an-xslt-file-and-xslt-if-statement))?

Comment: this is being done before I give the xml to the xslt.  If there is a way to do this in xslt I would love to know how but I couldn't seem to find one.

Comment: It can be done, but if you're not that familiar with XSLT, then this way is probably better.

Comment: Plus, XSLT is *horribly* verbose. It's not loved by all, for sure.

Comment: @Splashlin: Agreed - the logic is probably too complex for XSLT to handle anyway, though I'm no expert there...